# How to create a data table in Java

Tags: java, javascript, jquery

I need to create a table using a dataTable. I convert the data into json in servlet by using a eclipse tomcat 7. I use a Jquery plug-in in the code but its showing an error like: "Build in workspace encountered a problem". Here is the code I tried. Please try to fix my issue ....

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="DataTables-1.9.4/media       /js/jquery.js>     </script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="DataTables-1.9.4/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
var oTable = $('#tableId').dataTable( {
"processing": true,
"ajax": {
 "url": "/tabSrv",

"dataSrc": "demo",
"type": "GET",
}
} );
} );
</script>
```

Comment: Well, you are asking a question related to java and showing us code you have written in JavaScript. :)

Comment: Fix the src for the first 2 script tags, your oTable is correct.

Comment: I download latest datatable1.9.4 version it has three plugins jquery.js,jquery.datatable.min.js,jquery.datatables.js. I inserted these plugins in my project in eclipse. It shows this error "Building workspace encountered a problem". i dont know whether this problem related to eclipse or plugin. so, guide me how to solve this issue.